# Shortcut for launching taskbar app #11

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-8, taskbar

For launching `4th` app on my taskbar, I press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd>. This works for first 10 apps.

<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> will launch `10th` app on my taskbar.

But, I can't figure **how to launch 11th app on taskbar using a shortcut?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are limited to 10 apps using the `win + [number]` shortcut method. See full list of keyboard shortcuts below.

**Note:** This is a large image. Download it and zoom.

[image]

Comment: but the image doesn't say that win + 0 launches 10th app. so perhaps anyone else can confirm there is now way?

Comment: @goldenparrot, there is **not** a way to do this. There are only so many keys on a keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

If you have 11 items on the taskbar, you can press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> to highlight the first item, then press the <kbd>END</kbd> key to go to the last one. Not perfect, but it's a fast way to do it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can assign any key combination to do anything you want using [AutoHotKeys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/howto/RunPrograms.htm).

For example, the 11th app on my Taskbar is MDict.

This is one possible command to run MDict
All you need to do is to install AHK which is a very light program (2MB) and write a script like this"

```
#!1::
Run "C:\\MDicttPC\MDict.exe"
Return
```

Now <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> opens MDict. Here `#=Win , !=Alt`.

This is one possible script and certainly can be improved or elaborated.